# what's the limit for `cache api` limit for service worker?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

I know this has been asked so many times, but still I wanted to ask this because i found different articles stating different things.

**Here is what `developer mozilla` page says:**

there is global limit and group limit. global limit is 50% of free hard disk. So if we have 500GB free, browser is gonna have 250GB. Now, for each origin, there're groups. `www.example.com and example.com` is the same group and they are gonna be given 20% of `global limit` which is `250/5` = 50GB.

Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria

**Here is what Google Developers Page Says:**

```
Chrome  <6% of free space
Firefox <10% of free space
Safari  <50MB
IE10    <250MB
```

Link: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa#how_much_can_i_store

What's the final assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the browser and operating system. Even if you limit things to Chrome, there may be different behavior across "desktop", Android, and Chrome OS.

The guidance in "[Estimating Available Storage Space](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/estimating-available-storage-space)" should put you on the right path towards dynamically checking for available storage space, and calculating how much space your origin has already used. I'd recommend going with that dynamic approach that reflects the reality of the current operating system environment instead of any hardcoded assumptions.

Additionally, the [Persistent Storage API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/persistent-storage), when supported, can influence the behavior of the browser when it comes to storage pressure, so you should take that into account.

Comment: 1) The reason I posted this question is that link you posted can't work on safari. That's why I can't figure out what happens in safari. what do i do then?

2) chrome shows 286000MB as quota. is this per origin or the whole browser? how do I know how much is per origin if 286000MB is overal browser limit? if it's per origin, then 286000MB seems so large - it's the same as 286GB which is huge. what about other origins then? don't they need space too?

Comment: In Chrome, the answers you'll get back from the Storage Quota API are per-origin.

Comment: See also https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web.dev/pull/2752/files

Comment: I see that. Don't you agree to this? https://love2dev.com/blog/what-is-the-service-worker-cache-storage-limit/  (basically it says that everything depends on the volume size. for mobiles, limit can't be depending on percentage for some cases.  There should be an image on that link which shows that.